# Searching a string with different numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using an if statement where I'm trying to find a string that has different values. In particular I'm trying to find all the strings that contain "call:#" where # has different values, but there are other strings that have <call on them and I don't want those.  I'm looking for the generic symbol to search for any integer.

```
import pandas as pd

log = ['<band:3>20m\n', '<call:5>N5FFN\n', '<calling:5>N5FFN\n', '<cont:2>NA\n', '<country:24>United States of America\n', '<called:5>N5FFN\n', '<freq:6>14.328\n', '<call:6>N5FFPN\n', '<call:5>N5FFN\n']

for logs in log:
   if ("call:???? in logs:
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into utilising Regex,  Something along the lines of

```
import re

logs = ['band:320m\n', 'call:5N5FFN\n', 'calling:5N5FFN\n', 'cont:2NA\n', 'country:24United States of America\n', 'called:5N5FFN\n', 'freq:614.328\n', 'call:6N5FFPN\n', 'call:5N5FFN\n']

for log in logs:
    if (re.search(".*call[:][\d]*", log)):
        print(log)
```

however it seems like the numbers you've provided were hexadecimal, which would mean you need numbers and characters, so maybe use \w instead of \d

```
import re

logs = ['band:320m\n', 'call:5N5FFN\n', 'calling:5N5FFN\n', 'cont:2NA\n', 'country:24United States of America\n', 'called:5N5FFN\n', 'freq:614.328\n', 'call:6N5FFPN\n', 'call:5N5FFN\n']

for log in logs:
    if (re.search(".*call[:][\w]*", log)):
        print(log)
```

look here for more documentation
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: Genius.  That was incredible.  I used the hexadecimal version, I have to learn more on the "re".  Thanks so much for showing me this, really appreciate.  Also, thanks for reading the context of the problem.

Comment: No worries, good luck with your regex learning, it's important to know that while they can be super useful in certain scenarios, that they can take longer to process, so it's something to keep in mind if you are building a fast/performant system